# C# / Windows Forms - Display a PowerPoint slide-show without Office installed?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ms-office, powerpoint

I know I can display a Powerpoint presentation within my own form (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259369/embed-powerpoint-viewer-in-c-win-form)), but I'm wondering whether there is a way to get rid of Microsoft Office as a requirement?

I guess basically what I'm asking for is a library which will display Powerpoint slide-shows without my users having to install MS Office on every machine. They do not need to CREATE slide-shows, just display them. Does such a library exist? I have searched all over the place and I'm always referred back to the MS Interop / ActiveX stuff.

Any help is appreciated!

Tom

Answer (score 4):

Try this: [PowerPoint Viewer 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=048DC840-14E1-467D-8DCA-19D2A8FD7485&displaylang=en). Also see [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/739d453e-092e-46c3-8bc2-1836d5a9b4f8) about embedding a Powerpoint Viewer 2007 instance on a VB.NET form

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can accomplish this with [Aspose.Slides](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.slides-for-.net/default.aspx).  It can open up an PPT file you have, then I think you could save each sheet to a image.  Finally, you could show the images in your app.

Comment: I use Aspose and will confirm that you can create images from it. We upload the images to a web server in plain HTML wrappers with next/prev links. Obviously this won't work with animated/interactive slides though, in which case I would suggest the viewer Rubens Farias links to (which I have also used).

Comment: i am curious to know Aspose.Slides library is free?