# Include PowerPoint viewer into my WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, powerpoint

I want to display my PowerPoint presentation into a WPF application.

Requirements:

- Free (except PowerPoint is already installed on the PC)
- Has to be integrated into my WPF application, not an external one
- User must have the possibility to advance to the next slide, or go back
- Show animations

I tried 2 solutions:

- Using DSOFramer, but they recommend to not use it anymore, and it doesn't support 2010 files. It's a no go.
- Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint, but it opens the PowerPoint as an external application...
- Tried the tool http://www.edrawsoft.com but it cost like 3500$ the licence

I don't know where to go with this.... Thank you.

Edit:

Few months later, the only "good" solution that I can get all what I want (with animations, sound etc..) is to embed a c++ control... if wanyone have a solution for WPF and it's managed, I would like to know.

As for the given answer:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304662 : there is some problem using this with 2007 + files vs old one...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These links may help you

1. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304662
2. [Embed PowerPoint Viewer in C# Win Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259369/embed-powerpoint-viewer-in-c-sharp-win-form)

I found more codeproject article about hosting Powerpoint in WPF

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/118676/Embedding-PowerPoint-presentation-player-into-a-WP

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest of solutions, but one we had to go for a few years ago in a .NET 1.1 application.

**1.)** Provided that there is any application installed on the client system that a) can open Powerpoint files and b) has also installed a browser plugin to view them inside a browser window, you could use the `WebBrowser` control and `Navigate()` to the Powerpoint file.

If there is, for example, a MS office or OpenOffice installation on the client system, this would allow you to view Powerpoint presentations inside, say, Internet Explorer.

**2.)** An alternative approach was to use the [Microsoft Powerpoint Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6) and embed in a WinForms control. Unfortunately we had to use a very old version, I think for Office 2000, because newer version did not support embedding anymore as Microsoft told us. This might have changed in the meantime, but I do not know about that.

Answer (score 0):

I just know that with DevExpress 12 it is possible to integrate PowerPoint, Excel, Word and Outlook as a Control. So you can put a PowerPoint Control on your form like a Textbox. DevExpress is a really nice framework but the disadvantage is, that one license costs 900 dollars.

Comment: That's incorrect, according to this reply: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q550351