# create application like simple PowerPoint in c# wpf?

Tags: wpf, ms-office, powerpoint

I want to create create application like simple PowerPoint in c# WPF, I meant exactly that I want to create page like slides and can arrange in time line with various speed and transition and can seeing in preview panel.I tries on Microsoft PowerPoint interoperability but as I found It just create PowerPoint file not provide framework to interact!!.
Please show me sample code or sample way to-do or how do it?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Thanks for comment, Edited.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include PowerPoint viewer into my WPF application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432875/include-powerpoint-viewer-into-my-wpf-application)

Comment: have a look at tool Blend for Visual Studio. You can create animations in pure xaml without powerpoint, although it is not that simple as powerpoint. It's more like adobe illustrator

Answer (score 0):

One method I have used is to have a WPF `WebBrowser` control and then navigate to a pptx file. This will open PowerPoint inside the `WebBrowser` control. You will not be able to interact with the PowerPoint application from your WPF host, but that is about as good as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this control from syncfusion: http://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/presentation. They now offer a free community version with all if their controls.